# Why use git when I can drag and drop files into github?

Tags: git, github

Why use git when I can drag and drop files into github?
I had some errors while using git. So I just dragged and dropped the file into github.
So, why use git?

Comment: I feel like this question will evoke opinion-based answers.

Comment: Why use a computer, when an abacus will do?

Answer (score 1):

Git has several benefits, off the top of my head:

- checking out your local repository to any historical commit, which allows you  to run or build the code as it was at a previous commit
- branch management by allowing you to choose how to merge, resolve or (partially) apply changes from any  branch to another (although GitHub does allow for viewing and diffing various branches)
- making changes to existing files and committing those changes, since not every change you make will be a new file
- complex diffing, more advanced git features like `blame`, and many more advanced features

Comment: Working offline, editing multiple files at once, backups, rebasing, …